# Definition of the "zoom" tag

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I've answered a question today that has the [zoom] tag, and while checking the tag afterwards I noticed that:

- it has no definition or use recommendation
- it has been colonized lately by zoom.us.app questions (which I guess was not the intended use), as in the case of the question I answered

I've never created the use guide of a tag, and while I have no issue in reading some other tag guidelines and giving it a shot, I'd like to know what is the community consensus on the definition of the zoom tag.

In my opinion it should be used on the many instances of "zoom" functions when looking for "zoom" on the System Preferences, and not on the zoom.us.app which could have a separate tag if needed.

[image: searching for "zoom" on System Preferences]

Comment: Good question and thanks for bringing it up here. Without having given it much thought (about to rush off to a meeting), my initial view is that we'd want a separate tag for the zoom.us.app and we'd leave this for generic zoom functions. But of course, we'd want to ensure that we had some usage guidance on the tags (at a minimum, an excerpt).

Answer (score 5):

Unless we want to burninate the tag entirely, a second tag for zoom.app might help since the usage for this as an Accessibility feature seems to be the initial use in 2010. I’ve created [zoom.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoom.app) and fixed three posts that were tagged [zoom](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoom) but clearly mean the app.

- I don’t think we want or need it for questions on optical or digital zoom on cameras. (But I could be wrong if we unearth a bunch of posts on this)
- It’s not a great tag for Accessibility since it’s part of macOS or iOS or iPadOS as well as that so a merge / synonym might be appropriate there and helpful for our tag system.
- The third party app clearly has a lot of users during the pandemic, but do we treat it like Kleenex or Xerox or have a raft of meeting tags for the plethora of questions and tools (Teams, TeamViewer, GoToMeeting, Zoom, Blue Jeans, WebEx, MobileMeet, Adobe Connect, Google hangouts or Meet, FaceTime, Skype, Discord etc...)

We do already have [video-conference](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-conference)

Comment: Having both zoom and zoom.app won't work well - users tend to choose the first an not read the wiki so will choose zoom in many cases.

Comment: I think we need a 'raft' of meeting tags as the answers and environment will differ. What do we do for any random app - have a tag for each one? I think having an extra tag here does not cause a problem (unless the app name mixes with some common Apple name - of which Zoom is a good example)

Comment: I agree @mmmmmm unless some several people care to curate tags, if we can’t pick one we should make both synonyms of something that is safe and self correcting. Let me try a bit more to clean this week and we’ll see if a proposal has consensus.